# Convert parent class to child during execution

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a parent class named `SavableFile` and 2 class `SaveA` and `SaveB` inherited from `SavableFile`.

They are defined like this :

```
class SavableFile {
    SavableFile(std::string _filename) : p_filename(_filename){}
    virtual void write() = 0;
protected:
    std::string p_filename;
}

class SaveA : public SavableFile {
   SaveA(std::string _filename) : SavableFile(_filename) {}
   void write() {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl; 
   }
}

class SaveB : public SavableFile {
   SaveB(std::string _filename) : SavableFile(_filename) {}
   void write() {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl; 
   }
}
```

My question is: would it be possible to create a SavableFile and using the extension of the filename, convert this savableFile to saveA or saveB? Something like

```
 SavableFile(std::string _filename) : p_filename(_filename){
     std::string ext = GetExtension(_filename);   
     //this is purely fictionnal, it's only in order to give an idea, i'm not sure if there is a way to do that, that's why i'm asking
     if (ext.lower() == "a"){
          *this = dynamic_cast<SaveA>(*this);
     } 
     else {
          *this = dynamic_cast<SaveB>(*this);
     }
}
```

So that I could do something like this :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    SavableFile svA("foo.a");
    //Here, SavableFile has been changed into SaveA class because of the constructor of SavableFile
    svA->write();
    //Here should be writed "A"
    SavableFile svB("bar.b");
    svB->write();
    //Here should be writed "B"
}
```

I could always make the test in the main to check if I have to create a SaveA or a SaveB class, but I think it would be a less good approach of the problem. But I can't find a way to do that, and I'm not finding the good wording in order to find help somewhere... 
Is it possible?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can achieve the desired effect, but not in the way you imagine. Just read about polymorphism, virtual functions etc. I.e. in your base class declare `virtual void write() = 0` and implement (override) it in the derived classes. Then in main function `SavableFile *sf = new SaveA(...); sf->write();`.

Comment: If you have to do that, then you got serious design problems.

Comment: Yes! I know polymorphism, and the fact that I could do that. But I would like to do without having to call for `new SaveA(...)` somewhere. Just deduct it from the extension of the filename.

Comment: @BЈовић can you explain a little more what you're thinking? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: For me, your question sounds like a XY problem. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @RaphSchim, if you want to use polymorphism you cannot avoid dynamic allocation, I believe.

Comment: @vahancho seeing all the answer I get. It seems that you're right!

Comment: Basically, you should be able to use the interface, and not downcast. Read about [SOLID principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot convert an existing object to a different type.

An alternative approach would be the [named constructor pattern](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html):

```
class SavableFile {
  public:
    static SavableFile *create(std::string _filename); // named constructor
    virtual void write() = 0;
  protected:
    SavableFile(std::string _filename) : p_filename(_filename){} // actual constructor now protected
    std::string p_filename;
};

SavableFile *SavableFile::create(std::string _filename) {
     std::string ext = GetExtension(_filename);   
     if (ext.lower() == "a"){
          return new SaveA(_filename);
     } 
     else {
          return new SaveB(_filename);
     }
}
```

This does have the drawback of always returning a dynamically allocated pointer. To get around that, you could add another layer of abstraction: `SavableFile` would contain a `private FileSaver *p_filesaver`, where `FileSaver` is an interface containing just the `virtual void write()` function.

Comment: Technically this approach may work. But this design has another drawback - the base class "knows" classes that derive from it. It brakes so called "dependency inversion principle" which states that "Abstractions should not depend on details.". Besides, when you introduce a new file format, you must extend the base class too.

Comment: @vahancho True. We could move the named constructor into a free function, so the base class no longer "knows" about derived classes. But that doesn't reduce the problem, it just moves it. How would you design this better?

Comment: I afraid, I don't understand the very problem. I guess, OP doesn't want to create objects of derived classes? If so, it's impossible to achieve what he wants. Maybe using a free factory function would be the best approach.

Comment: as Ventu pointed out, it was probably an XY problem (and i'm sorry about that), I was just asking if there were a way to achieve what I wanted. But I understand now that the answer is obviously nope. It seems that the factory function is the "best" way and the one that approachs the most what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using *Factory Method* design pattern:

```
class Factory {
public:
    static SavableFile* get(std::string _filename) {
        std::string ext = GetExtension(_filename);
        if (ext.lower() == "a") {
            return new SaveA(_filename);
        } 
        else {
          return new SaveB(_filename);
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

**Full code:**

```
class SavableFile {
public:
    SavableFile(std::string _filename) : p_filename(_filename) {}
    virtual void write() = 0;
protected:
    std::string p_filename;
};

class SaveA : public SavableFile {
public:
    SaveA(std::string _filename) : SavableFile(_filename) {}
    void write() override {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl; 
    }
};

class SaveB : public SavableFile {
public:
   SaveB(std::string _filename) : SavableFile(_filename) {}
   void write() override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl; 
   }
};

class Factory {
public:
    static SavableFile* get(std::string _filename) {
        std::string ext = GetExtension(_filename);
        if (ext.lower() == "a") {
            return new SaveA(_filename);
        } 
        else {
            return new SaveB(_filename);
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SavableFile* svA = Factory::get("foo.a");
    // It is better to check here if the pointer is not null.
    svA->write();
    SavableFile* svB = Factory::get("bar.b");
    // It is better to check here if the pointer is not null.
    svB->write();

    delete svA;
    delete svB;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean SaveB in the else branch of your factory, right?